# How is the "partial" view used in the new Facebook Application achieved?

Tags: android, android-view

I am trying to create an application that, when the user pressed an item in a listview, opens up a new partial view with information about said item. I would like to implement it in a way that looks like what the Facebook dev Team did with their commenting section :

[image]

My question is: How do I go about achieving this ?
All I want is to open up a new view that only takes up part of the screen as shown above.

Comment: Based on that screenshot, it seems like a heavily customized Dialog or an Activity that looks like a dialog.

Comment: It could be done also by placing one more view on top of the rest, possible with RelativeLayout. To show or hide "setVisibility()"  method  can be used